# extracting cpu status and availablility from windows with win32_processor of wmi classes c++

Tags: windows, winapi, cpu-usage, win32-process

I need to extract some information about cpu with the help of WMI on windows embedded from win32_processor.I do the routine process on msdn that is on;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx

```
 CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
 CoInitializeSecurity
 CoCreateInstance and etc..
```

I succesfully take the cpu status and availability and it is not so slow.But when I do this job continiously with some delay and at the same time another application runs on the machine,It has performance problems because other application is running on processor and when i do extract data from processor the performance becomes slow.So is there another fast way of getting the properties of the CPU?

Comment: There are a bunch of performance counters available, they have less overhead.  Your question is too vague to recommend any particular ones.

Comment: @Hans.Yes they are but arent they take the data from the same place where WMI takes?.IF so,the same performance issue will happen.Can you advise a better way if you know?